# Have a website showing tech deals - after I list 9 products any new products I put in appear below product #9 instead of to its right

Tags: javascript, html, css, animate.css

I'm creating a website which shows off tech deals and I have put nine products down and after I insert a product after the ninth product instead of appearing to the ninth products left it appears below the ninth product.

I am using animate.css to animate the product's images sliding onto the webpage if that matters.

I'm new to this forum so I'm not sure what I should include in this post. So I will show you my index.html (home page) and my style.css (styling for home page).

Here is a link to the CSS and HTML:
https://jsfiddle.net/2cr8uLv2/

```
<h1> it says you need code and I can't enter my code here so I'm just making this</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the closing `</figure>` tag on the 9th item.